# Django HttpResponse Returning Empty Tarfile

Tags: python, django, httpresponse

I'm running a Django server on my local machine that is supposed to allow the user to download a tarfile which contains a graph file of some sort (.graphml, .gpickle, ect.).

```
def getResponse( filename ):

    output = tarfile.open('GeneratedGraph.tar.gz', mode='w')
    try:
        output.add(filename)
    except Exception, e:
      logger.warning("Unable to write to tar")
      raise OCPCAError("Unable to write to tar")
    finally:
        output.close()

    response     = HttpResponse(output,'application/x-gzip')
    response['Content-Length'] = os.path.getsize("GeneratedGraph.tar.gz")
    response['Content-Disposition'] = 'attachment; filename="GeneratedGraph.tar.gz"'
    return response
```

filename is the string of the name of the graph file being stored. The storage of the graph file into the .tar file works fine, and I've verified it was accurate. However when I actually call this method as the thing to be returned from the main method, I get a tarfile that is empty and much smaller than expected. I'm fairly new to Django, so Im sorry if I made a basic mistake but none of the examples received in other questions worked for me.

Comment: I have edited your post to partially fix the indentation in your sample code, but the snippet you have provided is not valid Python. Spacing is very particular in Python and if I simply fix it so that it is correct, it could mask errors in your actual code. Please fix your sample so that it is both correct but also the actual code you have, including any errors.

Comment: Try creating the response before actually writing to it. Just after defining it at the beginning of your function.

Comment: Thanks @Two-BitAlchemist I honestly just got lazy in the sample submission, sorry.

Comment: So I've tried doing it now using a wrapper around the tar file and sending that in the response instead: 
    `wrapper = FileWrapper(file("GeneratedGraph.tar.gz"))
    response     = HttpResponse(wrapper,'application/x-gzip')` 
Which seems to work fine, and I'm wondering why?